# Values over UITextField placed over UITableViewCell are getting lost

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I have placed UITextField over each  UITableView cell. While scrolling the UITableView cell the text over the UITextField is getting lost. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get track of an `NSMutableArray` which stores the text field values.  Make the initial values @"".  When you insert the text field into the cell, get the value from the appropriate value in the array.

If the text field exits, do something like this to store your text field values in the array:

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
    {
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)textField.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSMutableArray *rows=[sectionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSString *string=[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    string=textField.text;
    [[sectionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:string];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES; }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myCellId= @"myDateCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myCellId]; 
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                  reuseIdentifier: myCellId]; 

    CGRect textFieldFrame;
    CGRect labelFrame;
    labelFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+45, cell.frame.origin.y+3, labelWidth, cell.bounds.size.height-5);
    textFieldFrame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+labelWidth+15, cell.frame.origin.y+12 ,cell.
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelFrame];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:textFieldFrame];
    textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.text = [[sectionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    [cell addSubview:label];
    [cell addSubview:textField];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but This method is called after entering text but after scrolling how should I fetch the values entered previously and show that value in again in TextField ?

Comment: When the cell is made, it contains a textfield, and that textfield preloads its value from the correct entry in the array.  So just find out what row the cell is in the table and fetch that value from the array.(don't forget to preload the array with @"" in every spot for the default value.

Comment: Thanks James for giving me your valuable reply but while scrolling,how should I know that name of the visible textfields without clicking that.

Comment: you don't need to know the names of the textfield.  When each cell is created, you should add a textfield and put in the value for the textfield.  Get this value from the array.  Each cell is created every time is becomes visible

Comment: Thanks James..can you please give me this code or if you have any sample code please give me

Answer (score 0):

It's because as you scroll, the tableview dynamically creates and destroys cells to save on memory.  If you still haven't figured out a way to solve this problem let me know and I will help you find a solution